# Invoke response empty when execute PowerShell scripts in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, invoke, bios

I'm currently writing some code to execute PowerShell using C#.

Here is my code

```
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

            runspace.Open();

            // create a pipeline and feed it the script text
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

            ps.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

           // execute the script
            Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();

            //Close the runspace
            runspace.Close();

            // convert the script result into a single string
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            
            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
```

I will pass my command through scriptText variable.

I tried some commands like "Get-Process", "Get-Service",... and it worked fine.

But when I tried "Get-BIOS" from [GetBIOS module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/GetBIOS/1.3.1), it didn't. It returned an empty result.

I ran "Get-BIOS" command on the system's PowerShell with Admin's right, it showed a lot of information that I want.

What I've tried so far:

-Using app.manifest file to require Admin right when execute

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

-Or try execute this first to install the module first

> scriptText = "install-module GetBIOS"

and execute this after

> scriptText = "Get-BIOS"

But none of them worked.

How can I fix this, or can we have another way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could start by troubleshooting why it doesn't return anything: inspect `ps.HadErrors` and `ps.Streams.Error` after calling `ps.Invoke()`

Comment: Oh, I see "The term 'Get-BIOS' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again." error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Just try to change the project's Target Framework.

I've changed to .NET 4.8 and it worked.